# How to downlaod a csv file after writing data to it using python

Tags: python, csv, web.py

I am using web.py and creating a basic webpage,

I had a basic html code which has a button as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="POST" action="/retrieve">
      <button id="submit" name="submit">Retrieve</button>
   </form>
</body>
```

So by the above code i can able to see a button on a page, when we click on the button `Retrieve` the action attribute activates and goes to required path to perform operation

**index.py** code

```
import web
import csv

urls = (
  '/retrieve',   'Retrieve',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='Merion_dev', host='localhost')

class Retrieve:

    def POST(self):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM adm_facility LIMIT 0,10 "
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall() 
        csv_file = csv.writer(open('Test_File.csv', 'wb'))
        csv_file.writerow(['Facility_id', 'Name', 'Account Number', 'Street'])
        for i in result :
            csv_file.writerow([i[0],i[2],i[3],i[4]])
        raise web.seeother('/retrieve')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

So when i run the above code , a csv file is successfully created with data from database by the select query written.

Now what i want to do is, when we click on the retrieve button the data should be written in to csv file and should be downloaded like

In `phpmyadmin` when we click on `export` button a file will be downloaded in different formats according to our selection, so but here i wan t to download a file(csv) after saving data in to it.

Can anyone please let me know

1. How can we download the csv file after saving data in to it by the above code
2. How can we download the csv file using python in general ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to write it to a file, you could use StringIO for it:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import csv

import web

urls = (
  '/retrieve',   'Retrieve',
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
conn = mdb.connect(user='root', passwd='redhat', db='Merion_dev', host='localhost')

class Retrieve:

    def POST(self):
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query = "SELECT * FROM adm_facility LIMIT 0,10 "
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall() 
        csv_file = StringIO()
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        csv_writer.writerow(['Facility_id', 'Name', 'Account Number', 'Street'])
        for i in result :
            csv_writer.writerow([i[0],i[2],i[3],i[4]])
        web.header('Content-Type','text/csv')
        web.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=yourfilename.csv')
        return csv_file.getvalue()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hi andrean sorry for re-questioning for the answer that i had accepted before,in the above code we had only one query_1 "SELECT * FROM adm_facility LIMIT 0,10 ",and if we hit retrieve a csv file will be downloaded with the query_1 data,but now i am facing a situation where i will i have more than one query for which i had to generate separate csv file for each query results,ie.,for query_1 it should generate query_1.csv and for query_2 it should generate query_2.csv.

Comment: But when i tried to create a csv file by executing query_two, same previous csv file ie., query_1.csv is overwriting if same data exists and adding new rows if new data came from query so can u please let me know what to do in this scenario in order to generate separate csv files for each query results like query_1.csv and query_2.csv

Comment: Please check this question posted by me,where i have actually facing the problem....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019549/downloading-exporting-a-csv-file-when-clicked-on-a-button-in-web-py-python

Comment: you can serve only one file / request, so the query results should be either put in one file, or you can make multiple requests, and by reading the request query data decide which csv file to generate.