# How to empty the buffer stringIO in python

Tags: python, truncate, stringio

Actually i am trying to export a  csv file with some data and below is my code

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO
import web


def download(list__of_records):
    csv_file = StringIO()
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(['Name', 'Link'])
    for i in list_of_records :
         csv_writer.writerow([i[0],i[1]])
    web.header('Content-Type','text/csv')       
    web.header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=%s.csv'%file_name) 
    return csv_file.getvalue()

list_of_records_1 = [('name',"fedrik"),('age','73'),('city','portland')]
list_of_records_2 = [('name',"wow"),('age','466'),('city','asdsa')]

download(list_of_records_1)
```

Actually i will use the above code in some web page that downloads a csv with the `list_of_records` data.

In the above code i am using web which is nothing but web.py framework i ma using to instruct browser to download a csv ifle

suppose i called the function `download(list_of_records_1)` , then a csv file is downloaded with data in it as below

```
Name    fedrik
age         73
city        portland
```

suppose i call the same function with `download(list_of_records_2)` , the output saving in to the csv is as below

```
Name    fedrik
age         73
city        portland
Name    wow
age         466
city        asd
```

That is if the data already matching in csv then its overwriting and if new data is encountered then the csv file is creating with previous data as well as present `list_of_records_2` data.

So in the above code after storing the results in the buffer string `StringIO()` and saving in to csv file, we should truncate/delete the buffer string data, so that when we call the same function with other list of results the previous data will not be write in to csv file of the current one

Can anyone please let me know how to truncate the buffer string `StringIO()` in the above code ?

Comment: you know StringIO has a truncate() method, like for normal files?

Comment: yup but i tried and its not truncating the buffer string so approached SO, can u please refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019549/downloading-exporting-a-csv-file-when-clicked-on-a-button-in-web-py-python   This was my actual problem

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- don't agree: "s = StringIO.StringIO(); s.write('hello world\n'); s.truncate(0); s.seek(0); s.read()" -> returns empty string.

Comment: I may as well delete my answer, because your diagnosis of what is going wrong is not correct. You create a new `StringIO()` instance every time in `download()` so I think you are doing something else wrong here.

Comment: @isedev: Ah, I forgot there is an argument to `.truncate()` :-)

Comment: To make it absolutely clear: Creating a *new* `StringIO` object each time means it can *never* contain data from a previous CSV file.

Comment: Actually in my code i declared a shared variable web.some_vriable = [], which i am updating in every class, here i am looping through this list and saving the results to csv, probably this is the result for this, after completion of generating csv i should empty this list so that it will contains the data only from the next url in my scenario:) presently trying to check this out